# Unusual time picker

Tags: mobile, time, datetimepicker

I'm puzzled by the following time picker:

[image: A time picker displaying all even hours and all multiple of 5 minutes]

Proposing only the *even* hours is fine, but then why bother to propose minutes as well? It's strange to let the user choose `10.05` but not `11:00`.

If that matters, this picker is part of a mobile app selling train tickets, and selecting `10:00` will display all trains departing from a specific station after 10am.

This picker has been like that for about one year, so I suppose it's a deliberate choice. Maybe this design has been proven to be effective? If so I'd be curious to have some references.

Comment: What is the time picker selecting, exactly? Outbound trains? Do trains only leave every 5 minutes on even hours?

Comment: Yes it selects outbound trains. And trains can leave at any time.

Comment: What is the name of the app? Looking at it may help figure it out.

Comment: Trainline. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, if it's not clear why they are doing it, it's probably not a good design choice. Ideally in digital products most things should be self-evident and intuitive. Your best bet for figuring this out might be to email them and ask, because it is not clear at all why they choose this setup.